# trouble converting index to row

Tags: math, matrix, indices

I'm having trouble converting an index number into its respective column/row. The table goes like this

[image: table]

The graph scales in each dimension. Each square is surrounded by one blank space. I need to turn the number of the square into the x/y coordinates

I've figured out the column, but the row is still evading me.

This is what i have now:

```
#define IDtoX(n, w) ((2*(n%w))+1)
#define IDtoY(n, h) ((2*(n/h))+1)
```

`IDtoX` works as intended. `IDtoY` does not.

outputs should be as following.:

grid of width 7 and height 5:

```
n  y
0   3
1   3
2   3
3   1
4   1
5   1
```

grid of width 9 and height 7:

```
0   5
1   5
2   5
3   5
4   3
5   3
6   3
7   3
8   1
9   1
10  1
11  1
```

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/TTb9wGz.jpg

Comment: The graph scales in each dimension. Each square is surrounded by one blank space. I need to turn the number of the square into the x/y coordinates.

Comment: That additional information makes your question *much* better. SergGr beat me to editing that information into your question.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason why you are failing with your function `IDtoY(n, h)` is that the result also depends on the value of `w`. Therefore you must change your signature to something like `IDtoY(n, w, h)`. To see this, try drawing more arrays with the same `h`s but varying `w`s and you will see that the `id`s will also change for each `n`. You were fooled by your successful function for `IDtoX` which does indeed not depend on `h` but only on `n` and `w`. Now, if your `id`s began at zero at the top, they would not depend on `w`, but as you drew the array, they do.

I found multiple formulae that work, but none of them are pretty. Here are two--if you do not like them, you could find some equivalent formulae.

```
#define IDtoY(n, w, h) (h - 2 - 2 * n // (w - 1) * 2)
```

or perhaps

```
#define IDtoY(n, w, h) (h - 2 - n // (w // 2) * 2)
```

where the `//` operator is integer division. You do not state which computing environment you are using--the simple `/` operator may work for you.

Comment: Rory, I believe the `#define` term is a good sign of the C/C++ being used as the language and so integer division should be just `/`